# HP Pavilion g7 2300-sm reading only 920mb of RAM memory

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, hp-pavilion

My Pavilion g7 2300-sm have 4gb of RAM memory.

I have installed Win 7 (original) on him. What I didn't know is that this laptop is made only for Win8. I did manage to install all the drivers, and everything is working, but the system only reads 920MB of RAM memory in stead 3.2GB of 4GB possible (because is a WIN7 32-bit -- I need this exact WIN7 for work).

Did any one have the solution for this? I need it soon or I'll have to change my laptop because of this :(

Answer (score 2):

If your laptop only supports 64-bit operating systems, running 32-bit operating systems will result in large amounts of memory being inaccessible. Hardware mappings must be placed in the first 4GB of address space, so systems optimized for 64-bit operating systems move as much memory as possible out of the way to leave room for hardware mappings. Sadly, 32-bit operating systems can't access the moved memory (unless they support PAE, which Windows 7 doesn't).

Your BIOS might have a "memory remapping" option that you can turn off. But if not, you're just trying to make your machine do something it was never designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this model on [HP Website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4132&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5354949). The available OS for your system is Windows 8 or 8.1 - 64 bit with all drivers (in case of windows). Windows 7 is not listed there. So I would suggest you to install Windows 8/8.1-64 bit for `full memory usage`.

Hope this will help you.